# How do I subvert computer idle detection on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

In order to detect user absence [`GetLastInputInfo()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506051/how-to-know-the-computer-is-idle-now/506058#506058) can be used.

I want to make `GetLastInputInfo()` return that I've just used keyboard/mouse all the time - as I've been actively using the computer so that whoever relies on `GetLastInputInfo()` thinks I'm actively using the computer.

Can I use any Windows API functions to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`SendInput` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Can that be used without interfering with any concurrent real activity?

Comment: You could set a mouse or keyboard hook to check whether there is any real activity.  Alternatively, you could press the `F15` key.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to simply move the mouse up and down a bit (15 pixels or so) with [SendInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx)?. I can't remember if NT6+ only resets the timeout for real hardware input or not.

The other options are:

- Hook GetLastInputInfo with something like [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)
- Generate [real hardware input](http://www.wiebetech.com/products/MouseJiggler.php)

Answer (score 2):

What is this for? Do you just want to disable the screensaver? If that's the case, then you're probably better off looking at the [SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.